# Bartle 3.7.7 Comparison Test for convergence

Tags: real-analysis

[image: Proof as presented in textbook]

I am failing to follow the last line of this proof. Why does it follow that the series in x converges?‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

Thanks for your help

Comment: "*By definition?*"  We showed that for every $\epsilon$ there exists an $m,n$ such that...

Comment: Partial sums form a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: They are using the Cauchy criterion for convergence, try to apply this to the sequence of partial sums. If you want a more complete answer, consider reformatting your question so that it is aligned with what is expected from a stack exchange question. Guidelines can be found at https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question&ved=2ahUKEwiAldHqqteBAxVcUUEAHQ4dBiIQFnoECCUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3O5bRgjEVERMyuyayWLY4c

Comment: I see, thank you very much

Comment: @JMoravitz it isn't quite "by definition" the definition of convergence of a series (at least in this textbook) is given as the convergence of the sequence of partial sums, and a sequence being cauchy is not the definition of a sequence converging although they are equivalent